# Spree module decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator, spree

I'm using Spree Commerce for my Online Shop. I want to change some behaviour during the checkout process, that is defined in `app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb` inside the spree gem. So I made a `checkout_decorator.rb` at the same point in my application.

The problem is, that my changes aren't loaded. And another problem is, that everything inside the module is inside one method, the `def self.included(klass)` method. So I think I have to overwrite the whole file, instead of just one method. Here is what my decorator looks like:

`checkout_decorator.rb`

```
Spree::Order::Checkout.module_eval do
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      class_attribute :next_event_transitions
      class_attribute :previous_states
      class_attribute :checkout_flow
      class_attribute :checkout_steps

      def self.define_state_machine!
         # here i want to make some changes
      end

      # and the other methods are also include here
      # for readability, i don't show them here
    end
  end
end
```

The original file `checkout.rb` from the spree gem looks like this:

```
module Spree
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    module Checkout
      def self.included(klass)
        klass.class_eval do
          class_attribute :next_event_transitions
          class_attribute :previous_states
          class_attribute :checkout_flow
          class_attribute :checkout_steps

          def self.checkout_flow(&block)
            if block_given?
              @checkout_flow = block
              define_state_machine!
            else
              @checkout_flow
            end
          end

          def self.define_state_machine!
             # some code
          end

          # and other methods that are not shown here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So my questions are: Why does this not work? Is `module_eval` the right way to do this? I tried `class_eval` but it doesn't work either. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The module_eval method isn't going to work for you.

You should look at the [Spree Checkout Flow Documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html#modifying-the-checkout-flow) for some good examples on how to customize the checkout flow.  This is the recommended way for customizing the checkout flow as you won't need to copy/paste a whole bunch of code.

Answer (score 1):

The namespacing isn't right.

Try `Spree::Order::Checkout.class_eval do`

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Overwrite the method you want in the Spree::Order class instead of the Spree::Order::Checkout module.

You mentioned that in the original file (spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb) there's a method wrapping the entire module.

```
def self.included(klass)
  klass.class_eval do
```

This method is called when the module is included in a class, and does its own `class_eval` to add the module's methods to instances of the class including it.

So since (spree_core-3.2.0.rc3/app/models/spree/order.rb) has this line:

```
include Spree::Order::Checkout
```

We can add a decorator to the order class itself (app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb)